# access xml website without domain name

Tags: php, xml, sitemap

I have problems accessing pages on xml without domain (access ip address directly)

this is my ip address : http://107.170.117.8/

this is xml page that i want to access : http://107.170.117.8/xml-reference/index.xml

i want to access directly xml without domain, but it seems can't.

So, is there anyway i can access xml page without domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can access a site via a domain name,  but not an ip address,  there may be a few reasons:

- you might have the wrong ip address.  It's common for a webserver to have multiple ip addresses.
- the server might be configured to be using  name based virtual hosts.  This is probably the issue.
- less commonly, the server might be using ipv6

The answer is within your question: use the domain.